# Is there way to make librdkafka single threaded using epoll/select?

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

I wanted to run librdkafka as single-threaded application, is there any way to achieve this?

It looks like minimum 2 threads are needed to run librdkafka C client. Is there any way listed to achieve this or too many changes are needed for this to work?